# kubernetes deployment- container not starting- error- InvalidImageName

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, containers, ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

Below is the Kubernetes deployment yaml file `-container` image section:

```
image: https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/****/test-service:test-branch-67

imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Below is the error message after deploying:

> ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~$ kubectl logs test-deployment-69c6d8xxx -n test
>
> Error from server (BadRequest): container "test-deployment" in pod "test-deployment-ccccxxx" is waiting to start: InvalidImageName

Another error log:

> Failed to apply default image tag "https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/test/test-service:test-branch-66": couldn't parse image reference "https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/test/test-service:test-branch-66": invalid reference format

Any idea why the pod is not coming up?

Comment: Had the same issue then turned out the pipeline that was creating the image was failing.

Answer (score 12):

Remove the `https://` from the image name, and if you are using a private registry, make sure to use `imagePullSecrets`.

Comment: What do you mean by imagePullSecrets?

Answer (score 2):

> This could be because in your YAML file your image name would be wrong, maybe a tag missed, you can trace from there.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your complete deployment file to know the problem in detail. But looking at the file make sure you are not missing

> imagePullSecrets (Add valid credentials with access to pull the image from repository)

Also you need not provide the protocol like you added

> https

Your image field in yml should look like below example:

> image: repository:organization_name/image_name:image_version

Answer (score 0):

```sh
curl --insecure -sfL https://192.168.2.217/v3/import/zc2t5qstv4l9f6wv8stmfsqcks47x7z5m4xnnrbf7hn9c9vj65bwd7_c-4mdds.yaml  > tmp.yaml

# edit tmp.yaml file and delete https:/hub.docker.com/rancher/rancher-agent:v2.5.7 => rancher/rancher-agent:v2.5.7
# apply again:
kubectl apply -f tmp.yaml
```